# Simulating cleaning map in ROS

Tags: ros, navigation, 2dlidar, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to simulate a roomba using ROS. For planning the path and to figure out what area to clean next, I would like to maintain a map where the known cells are the ones visited by the robot and the grey ones are yet to be visited. Obviously feeding laser scans to slam won't generate such a map. My initial attempt was to add a fake lidar to the bot and restrict it's range to denote the cleaning area but when I remapped this data to gmapping the boudaries were labelled as obstacles which is undesired.

How can I efficiently create an OccupancyGrid for a cleaning robot where the known areas in the map denote the areas which the bot has cleaned?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389330/simulating-cleaning-map-in-ros/) by [ashwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/59677/ashwin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you are describing is functionality that is out of scope for `move_base` or the costmaps that it maintains. I would create a new ros node that operates conceptually at a higher level than `move_base`.

The job of this new node is to choose the next goal to give to `move_base`. It maintains its own map, with a grid of visited locations (populated by monitoring the robot pose.) This node will also need to know where the walls and prohibited zones are so it doesn't request an impossible-to-reach goal.

P.S. you will make the problem more difficult if you also try to mix in gmapping functionality. I would keep these two features separate until you are have more experience with ros.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/59677/ashwin/) on 2021-11-03**:
Thank you! For anyone stuck on the same problem, [this](https://github.com/nobleo/full_coverage_path_planner/blob/master/nodes/coverage_progress) might  be a good starting point. It was for me :)